# Clarification regrading String concatenation and addition?

Tags: java

**Why do i get 10 2030 as the out put? I cant figure out why it doesnt output it as 10 50 ?**

```
public class Testing1 {
public static void main (String args[]){
    int num1=10,num2=20,num3=30;

    System.out.println(num1+" "+num2+num3);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more clearly? Sorry im just a beginner

Comment: Without `(num2 + num3)` ,`+` is overloaded. It is concatenating the values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does not work because the expression is interpreted from **left** to **right** taking into account [operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Walk through it.

```
System.out.println(num1+" "+num2+num3);
```

First you take your `num1` and concat a space onto it, you now have "`10`".

Second you concat `num2` onto that string, you have "`10 20`".

Third you concat `num3` onto that, you have "`10 2030`".

In fact, what you are doing is this:

```
String s = num1 + " ";
s += num2;
s += num3;
```

Comment: +1 for the breakdown of expression

Answer (score 7):

[Operator precedence](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~ricko/CSE8A/Java_Operator_Precedence_Table.pdf)

```
System.out.println(num1+" "+(num2+num3));
```

While evaluation expressions,

> [Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) with higher precedence are evaluated before operators with relatively lower precedence. Operators on the same line have equal precedence.When operators of equal precedence appear in the same expression, a rule must govern which is evaluated first. All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated from `**left to right**`; assignment operators are evaluated right to left.

```
 System.out.println(num1+" "+num2+num3);

 --------------------10-----------------num1
 --------------------10 -----------------num1+" "
 --------------------10 20-----------------num1+" "+num2
 --------------------10 2030-----------------num1+" "+num2+num3
```

So, now you come to know that why you got that output.

Let see how the below statement gives you desired output:

```
System.out.println(num1+" "+(num2+num3));
```

Again based on the precedence, parentheses have the high precedence than `+`. So

`(num2+num3)`

evaluates first and the rest is same.

Comment: Im just looking for an explanation why it does not work that way?

Comment: @Razor1692 coz number + string + number = concatenated_stringNumber

Comment: @Razor1692  I edited to an extent. Hope that clears :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
System.out.println(num1 + " " +(num2 + num3));
```

If you're writing `(num1 + " " + num2 + num3)` Java will make a String from `num1` add the String `" "` to it, add the String made from `num2` to it and then add the String made from `num3` to it.

The plus first gets evaluated as String concatenation and not the math + sign.

Comment: Im just looking for an explanation why it does not work that way ?

Answer (score 1):

Beacause Precedence wise i.e left to right:

`num1+" "` will be evaluated making a string of `10`

`num2+num3` will simply be appended to that string because of `+` operator in-between

`num1+" "` and `num2+num3` forming `10 2030`

try this way

```
System.out.println(num1+" "+(num2+num3));
```

For more about precedence and their associativity : http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~palsetia/java/precedenceTable.html

Comment: How can i understand this through operator precedence?? I understood it as when num1+" " expression is there, since we add a string to the number ,java automatically converts the num1 into a string.So afterwards all the other numbers are converted to strings and added to that string.

Comment: precedence wise.evaluation starts from left to right..so num1+"" evaluated first.if it was right to left..num2+num3..will evaluate in that case

Answer (score 1):

make it `System.out.println(num1+" "+ (num2+num3));`
When you introduce any string when performing operations, then the concatenation happens instead of actual operation.

So if you do `System.out.println(num1+num2+ " " +num3);`. You will get the output as `30 30` This is because your operations are performed before string concatenation is introduced in it. and hence the operation result is produced.

Keep in mind that all operands will be treated as string AFTER the first concatenation has occurred.

Before the concatenation, all operations will be evaluated.

Comment: How can i understand this through operator precedence?? I understood it as when num1+" " expression is there, since we add a string to the number ,java automatically converts the num1 into a string.So afterwards all the other numbers are converted to strings and added to that string.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that output is that the `+` in this context (`num1 + " "` happens first) is treated as a concatenation operator and the rest is then concatenated too. The other answers suggest parentheses to ensure the num2 and num3 are added first before the string evaluation.