# Java: find the output of the code with double quotes and assignment operator

Tags: java

what will be the output of the following code and please explain me the output
code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
System.out.println(""+4+2);
System.out.println(4+2+"");
}
```

Comment: I might be wrong but please do your homework / interview quiz yourself.

Comment: [Click me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441552/clarification-regrading-string-concatenation-and-addition/20441562#20441562)

Comment: Try it out and you will see what the output is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.println(""+4+2); -> 42
```

Because first you are adding and empty string and a int value. Result will be a string. Then you are adding an another int to that string. So it will concatenate the just string representation of value to the previous string and output 42

```
System.out.println(4+2+""); -> 6
```

Here you are first adding 2 integers so it will results 6 as a int value. Then you are adding empty string to that int value. So the final result will be 6 as a string

Answer (score 0):

In Java Expression is evaluated from left to right with honor of precedence.

In you case There is only 1 operator +. So let's ignore precedence.

first case it will be 42

e.g.

```
System.out.println("" + 4 *2)  === 8

System.out.println("" + 4 + 2) === 42
```

In first case * will have precedence and in second case expression will be evaluated from left to right.

In second case it will be 6. In first case you are adding 4 and 2 to existing string "" .

(Apply left to right evaluation)

Answer (score 0):

You will find the answer from the byte code: use `javap -v className`

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   Stack=2, Locals=1, Args_size=1
  //some code
   3:   ldc     #22; //String 42 
   //some code
   11:  ldc     #30; //String 6



const #22 = String      #23;    //  42
const #30 = String      #31;    //  6
const #31 = Asciz       6;
```

So, basically during compile time, your code is effectively :

```
System.out.println(""+42); \\string + string+ string
System.out.println(6+"");   \\ number + number + string
```

The constants are added based on type from left to right

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println(""+4+2);` **-->** You have an empty `String`(`""`) and you add to it 4 and then 2. Now adding something on a `String` doesn't mean operating arithmetic addition. It means appending a `String` by a character or a set of characters. This is called ***String concatenation*** and the `+` implies that, when at least one of the 2 operands is a `String`. So here the result is `""+4+2 = 42` with 42 being a `String`

`System.out.println(4+2+"");`**-->** Here you have the same thing **but** you have an arithmetic operation first. So after doing `4 + 2` java sees a `String` and a `+` and turns the entire thing into a `String`. So the result is `6+"" = 6` with 6 being a `String` too.

Note that, the reason this is happening is because you have the same operation(`+`) and operations are being executed from left to right in the same order. Assuming the on this example,
 `System.out.println(""+4+2);` you had a multiplication or division, you would get these 2 operations being executed first, before the concatenation. For example:

`System.out.println(""+4*2);` would print **8**
`System.out.println(""+4/2);` would print **2**